# New items in Django admin do not have auto-incremented IDs in PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, auto-increment

I have a Django application, and I'm using the Django admin panel to manage my database. I have items with non-sequential IDs (i.e. 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9 for example), but when I try to add a new item, it will go to the first unfilled ID (3 in my example), which is fine, but then it will try to insert something into ID 4, which is already occupied. This throws an integrity error.

I'm using DataGrip and this is the 'default' value:
`nextval('<schema>.<table>'::regclass)`

I tried using `SERIAL` as the datatype but DataGrip rejected it.

My goal: get PGSQL to find the lowest value ID that isn't assigned, and assign that to the object being inserted. If the next value is taken, it should jump to the next available lowest value.

If this is not possible, is there a way to get PGSQL to start at a certain number (i.e. 400) and start auto-incrementing from there?

And lastly, is there a way for Django to manage the auto-incrementation as opposed to PGSQL?

Comment: It seems that some where your own code is deciding to use `3` as an ID. postgresql or django will not do that on it's own.

Comment: @e4c5 Thanks for your comment. I used three as an example to give to explain the situation. It'll pick different things depending on different tables, and it's always the lowest unclaimed number consecutively going up, regardless of availability. So I think I've isolated the problem to the database (unless you have any idea of what could be in my code, which is pretty simple). Anything in the database maybe? Are there other ways to sequence in SQL?

Comment: no this is definitely nothing at all to do with postgresl. __postgresql will not attempt to fill gaps in sequences__ this is well documented and experienced by thousands of others (as a cursory search here will reveal).You have some code of your own which is attempting to fill gaps

Comment: @e4c5 I just reproduced the error. Here's the message:
`IntegrityError at /admin/web/judge/add/
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "judge_id_pk"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(6) already exists.` Any specific suggestions on where to check in the code? It's very rudimentary so I'm not sure what could be causing it.

Comment: Since i have absolutely no idea about what your code looks like I have no ssuggestions. but my previous comments are still valid

Comment: @e4c5 I think I solved it. There was some code that tried to explicitly assign the id number. So you were right. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad it's sorted out.